# R tibble: If specific value in one row, how to get the value from the same column in the row before?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning

So there is this dataframe:

```
structure(list(`Industry, sex, and race` = c(NA, NA, NA, "TOTAL", 
"Agriculture and related", "Mining, quarrying, and oil and gas extraction", 
"Construction", "Manufacturing", "Durable goods", "Nondurable goods"
), `2021` = c("Total employed", NA, NA, NA, "2291", "603", "11271", 
"14718", "9349", "5369")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

which looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 2
   `Industry, sex, and race`                     `2021`        
   <chr>                                         <chr>         
 1 NA                                            Total employed
 2 NA                                            NA            
 3 NA                                            NA            
 4 TOTAL                                         NA            
 5 Agriculture and related                       2291          
 6 Mining, quarrying, and oil and gas extraction 603           
 7 Construction                                  11271         
 8 Manufacturing                                 14718         
 9 Durable goods                                 9349          
10 Nondurable goods                              5369
```

I found this script which cleanes the data quite impressively and does the following step:

```
clean_2020 <- df %>% 
  rename(category = 1) %>% 
  mutate(
    race_gender = if_else(
      str_detect(category, "Agriculture and related"),
      lag(category),
      NA_character_
    ),
    .before = category
  )
```

This essentially gets the row before the value `Agriculture and related` and puts it into a new column called `race_gender`

```
   race_gender category                                      `2021`        
   <chr>       <chr>                                         <chr>         
 1 NA          NA                                            Total employed
 2 NA          NA                                            NA            
 3 NA          NA                                            NA            
 4 NA          TOTAL                                         NA            
 5 TOTAL       Agriculture and related                       2291          
 6 NA          Mining, quarrying, and oil and gas extraction 603           
 7 NA          Construction                                  11271         
 8 NA          Manufacturing                                 14718         
 9 NA          Durable goods                                 9349          
10 NA          Nondurable goods                              5369
```

I wondered if I can do this by extracting the value in the column that comes immediately before `Agriculture and related`. I think I have some misconceptions in my head how I can refer to and deal with columns in a `mutate` in dplyr.
However, I did the following:

```
df %>% 
    rename(category = 1) %>% 
    mutate(
        race_gender = case_when(
            str_detect(category, "Agriculture and related") ~ category[row_number() - 1],
            TRUE ~ NA_character_
        )
    )
```

However this creates the error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `race_gender`.
ℹ `race_gender = case_when(...)`.
x `str_detect(category, "Agriculture and related") ~ category[row_number() - 
    1]` must be length 10 or one, not 9.
```

And I'm not entirely sure why and how I could solve this going this way.

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what you want the result to be. Which value do you want in your new `race_gender` column when `category` is `"Agriculture and related"`?

Comment: Do you mean "rows" in the last part of your question rather than columns? There are no columns immediately before the first column. I think what you're getting at is how you can replicate the workings of `lag` by detecting the row number of a match (and subtracting 1)? My only suggestion here is that `tidyverse`/`mutate` tends to ignore row numbers, which is exactly what `lag` is for.